# Swift Tap vs Long Press Buton

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am new to swift, so thanks for all the help... I am working on my first app and this works great if my button is press it goes into the didTap function.. But I need to do something else if its a LONG HOLD on the button...

Being new to this I need some help please... Here is more of the code so you can understand my coding, style,

***As of right now NONE of the examples worked***

```
var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            
            Color.black.ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text(currentValue)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.system(size: 72))
                }
                .padding()
                
                ForEach(buttons, id: \.self) { row in
                    HStack {
                        ForEach(row, id: \.self) { button in
                            Button {
                                buttonTapped(button: button)
                            } label: {
                                HStack {
                                    Text(button.rawValue)
                                        .foregroundColor(button.foregroundColor)
                                        .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .semibold))
                                        .frame(width: button.getButtonWidth(), height: button.getButtonWidth())
                                    
                                    if(button.isZeroButton) {
                                        Spacer()
                                    }
                                }
                                .frame(width: button.width, height: button.height)
                                .background(button.backgroundColor)
                                .cornerRadius(button.height)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(.bottom)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you could just use `Text` instead of a `Button`, such as:

```
    ForEach(row, id: \.self) { item in
        Text(item.rawValue)
            .font(.system(size: 32))
            .frame(width: self.buttonWidth(item: item),height: self.buttonHeight())
            .background(item.buttonColor)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .cornerRadius(self.buttonWidth(item: item)/2)
            .onTapGesture {
                // put your button action here
                self.didTap(button: item)
                print("---> onTapGesture")
            }
            .onLongPressGesture {
                print("---> onLongPressGesture")
            }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

We use `onTapGesture` for tap actions, and `onLongPressGesture` for long press actions:

```
Button(action: {}, label: {
   Text(item.rawValue)
       .font(.system(size: 32))
       .frame(width: self.buttonWidth(item: item), height: self.buttonHeight())
       .background(item.buttonColor)
       .foregroundColor(.white)
       .cornerRadius(self.buttonWidth(item: item)/2)
       .onTapGesture { //action for Tap }
       .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.5) {
        action()
    }
})
```

Comment: there is no such thing as `doLongPress()`.  There is a `onLongPressGesture{...}`, but even that, using this approach will loose the button action functionality.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I created a function in `extension View`
`func doLongPress(action: @escaping () -> ()) -> some View { self.onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.5) { action() }  }`